# Is there a scripting language that 'compiles' to windows batch syntax?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd

Is there a language, similar to what [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) is to JavaScript, that compiles to the language of the windows batch|cmd|command line?

The cmd versions I refer to are the ones based on NT, especially XP sp3 and up.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't think there is. You can lookup PowerShell, but it doesn't compile to `.bat`

Comment: @ChrisF Batch is "preinstalled" on most NT-based windows box, but writing in cmd syntax is something I forgot very easily.

Comment: +1 Interesting idea. The traditional solution to the grave and utterly frustrating lack of basic features of the `.bat` interpreter has been to simply replace it with something a bit less dumb, but wrapping it with another language ought to be possible. Maybe the target audience was lured away by INTERCAL and Befunge?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there is one language called Batsh, which compiles to both Bash and Windows Batch.

Project: https://github.com/BYVoid/Batsh

Online demo: http://batsh.byvoid.com/

Comment: Agreed.  Very awesome.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, what you're asking for doesn't exist, although it would be possible to create such a language, and it would be an intersting exercise.

The alternative is other languages that are also "built-in" to the OS.

Others have mentioned PowerShell, which is very powerful, and is built in, I think, in Win7 and up.

The other alternative is the Windows Script Host for which you can write scripts in VBScript and/or Javascript.  It's built-in to WinXP and up.

Comment: It would be VERY difficult, because batch is a very limited language. It may be possible to generate a bash script. But I liked the idea of the question:-)

Comment: @anishsane - I agree that it would be challenging, but `batch` is Turing complete so it is possible.  Depending on the constrcuts in the language you're compiling you'd end up with some pretty gnarly batch code.

Answer (score 1):

Just for your edification, CoffeeScript is a domain specific language built on JavaScript, so you could in theory intermingle the two. I am not aware of such a language for batch files. The windows powershell might be worth a look see.